# jquery validation dynamic rules messages

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-validate

One input needs a validation from 1-9999999 and the other 1-100% percent.  Each input has a dynamic value.  So you can keep adding more entry.  The new entry does not come with any validation? Too much `code` to put on here.

http://jsfiddle.net/ayang10/X5EvD/43/

Comment: You barely state what you want to achieve and nothing else.  Read this:  [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  What are we supposed to do with ASP code?  JavaScript uses the HTML markup that's **rendered** within the browser DOM, so only show us that.

Comment: BTW - you cannot call `.validate()` twice on the same element.  Remove `$form.validate()` above your `.each()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently I had to add the attribute for required, min, and max inside my javascript.

```
$('#entries').append(
        '<tr>' +
        '<td><input id="cl_' + count + '" name="cl[' + count + ']' + '" size="10" type="text" class="required" min="1" max="9999999" /></td>' +
        '<td><input id="num_' + count + '" class="required" min="1" max="100" name="num[' + count + ']' + '" type="text" size="5" /></td>' +
        '<td><span class="delete">Remove</span></td></tr>');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ayang10/X5EvD/43/